# html2canvas, only half of image is drawn or not draw some image

Tags: html2canvas

I am using html2canvas to capture entire of webpage but got problem some image can not draw or draw half of image. See my attachments.

This is my code

```
var config = {
  proxy: base_url + "proxy",
  logging: true
};

html2canvas(document.body, config).then(function (canvas) {
  my_image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

  resolve(true);
});
```

I tried `html2canvas 1.0.0-rc.1` and `html2canvas 1.0.0-rc.5` but not luck.
Also try set image timeout option, also try to remove some html element to make sure html page not too large but same result.

This is origin image

[image]

This is the capture result (please don't mind the line in image, I just added it)
[image]

Any help!

Comment: Are using any framework? aka React, angular...?

Comment: I am using pure JS

Answer (score 0):

After all, I found problem is max canvas height around 16.000px, my canvas went to 30.000px height.
So I split to many parts and store it.